# How can I add a button with a gradient border to my website?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, elementor

My issue is that the button appears very small, and I'm adjusting the height or width below does nothing.

I've input the code into my WordPress site using Elementor, I just dragged a HTML widget and pasted the below code.

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
}
.btn {
  padding: 20px 60px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #00FFA3, #DC1FFF);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.btn::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 1px;
  right: 1px;
  top: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: 200ms
}
.btn::after {
  content: attr(data);
  font-size: 16px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #00FFA3, #DC1FFF);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  transition: 200ms
}
.btn:hover::before {
  opacity: 50%;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
.btn:hover::after{
  color: white;
}






body .container {
  height: 10vh;
  width: 20vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
}

body .btn {
  padding: 20px 60px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #00FFA3, #DC1FFF);
  cursor: pointer;
}

body .btn::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 1px;
  right: 1px;
  top: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: 200ms;
}

body .btn::after {
  content: attr(data);
  font-size: 16px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #00FFA3, #DC1FFF);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  transition: 200ms;
}

body .btn:hover::before {
  opacity: 50%;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

body .btn:hover::after {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="btn" data="Click me"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. The demo appears as you describe your goal. Please see [ask], then revise to be more clear about the problem. You'll need to use your browser's document inspector to see what other styles might be affecting your button.

Answer (score 1):

I do your button bigger than on your page (just on .btn write height and width).

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
}

.btn {
  padding: 20px 60px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #00FFA3, #DC1FFF);
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 550px;
  #do width height: 150px;
  # do height
}

So good day;
) .btn::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 1px;
  right: 1px;
  top: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: 200ms
}

.btn::after {
  content: attr(data);
  font-size: 16px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #00FFA3, #DC1FFF);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  transition: 200ms
}

.btn:hover::before {
  opacity: 50%;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.btn:hover::after {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="btn" data="Click me"></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code and it looks like width and height is adjustable... Also you don't need to change `.container` width/height to change button size, you have to adjust padding attribute of `.btn` element. If adjusting padding attribute doesn't work it might be that your CSS is overwritten by Elementor/Theme, try to add !important to your padding attributes e.g `padding: 20px 60px !important;`

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
}
.btn {
  padding: 30px 70px !important;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #00FFA3, #DC1FFF);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.btn::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 1px;
  right: 1px;
  top: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: 200ms
}
.btn::after {
  content: attr(data);
  font-size: 16px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #00FFA3, #DC1FFF);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  transition: 200ms
}
.btn:hover::before {
  opacity: 50%;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
.btn:hover::after{
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="btn" data="Click me"></button>
</div>
```

To figure out if it is overwritten, press F12 to open DevTools and check your `.btn` CSS. If it's crossed out that means it's overwritten:

[image]

Comment: I think you are right, the issue is not with the code but with elementor overwriting my css

Comment: @Playejdhs Have you tried my suggestion? I mean !important property. Btw you can use inspect DevTools to check if it's overwritten...

Comment: Yeah, I tried to insert Important everywhere i could to override the CSS but it still looks nothing like in the preview

Comment: If you look at the code I've pasted at the end of my answer, it seems to work better but its within a container, so not sure if it will cause any issues.

Comment: @Playejdhs Your initial goal is to change button size right? So you don't need to change width/height of container, you have to change padding attribute of `.btn` element.

Comment: I wanted to change the width/height because it was showing up like 5px wide on my website, but the size was actually fine, it was just elementor forcing it to look like that.

Comment: @Playejdhs Can you share a link your website for better understanding?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the height and width in the .btn style allows you to change the button size.

`.btn { height: 200px; width: 400px; padding: 20px 60px;}`

[image]